# Error adding security configuration in existing spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to add security configuration in order to permit access for different roles for an existing application. The application is now running with a login page that searches for the login and pwd in the databases and gives access for every kind of role, but now I want to restrict access to some pages for some roles.

I've created a new class `WebSecurityConfig` that extends from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/img/**","/html/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").passwordParameter("pwd").usernameParameter("login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();          
    }
}
```

I 've tried to run the app with that code before restricting pages but it's not working and I don't know why. I think I'm missing something but I can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the console output.

```
DEBUG o.a.c.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer - Received [POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 57
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=84EB0B71EBA3D1A8646BD85AC97B2FA4; JSESSIONID=86BB75F3F05FF03573FBDA095231E676

login=1&pwd=11&_csrf=540de3b5-7baa-4720-ac37-968e1317a777]
DEBUG o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter - The variable [uriBC] has value [/login]
DEBUG o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter - The variable [semicolon] has value [-1]
DEBUG o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter - The variable [enc] has value [utf-8]
DEBUG o.a.t.u.http.LegacyCookieProcessor - Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=84EB0B71EBA3D1A8646BD85AC97B2FA4; JSESSIONID=86BB75F3F05FF03573FBDA095231E676
DEBUG o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter -  Requested cookie session id is 84EB0B71EBA3D1A8646BD85AC97B2FA4
DEBUG o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase - Security checking request POST /login
DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -   No applicable constraints defined
DEBUG o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase -  Not subject to any constraint
DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters - Set encoding to UTF-8
DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters - Start processing with input [login=1&pwd=11&_csrf=540de3b5-7baa-4720-ac37-968e1317a777]
DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@e3f1c10
DEBUG o.s.c.s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - Loading properties [messages.properties] with encoding 'UTF-8'
DEBUG o.s.c.s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [classpath:messages_es] - neither plain properties nor XML
DEBUG o.s.c.s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [classpath:messages_es_ES] - neither plain properties nor XML
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@e3f1c10
DEBUG o.a.c.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer - Received [GET /login?error HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=84EB0B71EBA3D1A8646BD85AC97B2FA4; JSESSIONID=86BB75F3F05FF03573FBDA095231E676

]
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information what *is not working*? You get 401? Empty pages? Stacktrace? etc.

Comment: Sorry, I get /login?error. Here is the console output.

Comment: Solved. I just need CustomUserDetailServiceImpl.

Comment: Can you self-answer your question, so further users will also value from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just need a CustomUserDetailService class.

Thanks.